# pdf.js is not working for IE 9 and 10

Tags: pdf.js

I've tested my code and it works on Chrome and Firefox but doesn't render in IE version 9 and 10.

I've tried using [hack.js](https://gist.github.com/notmasteryet/1057924) and [compatibility.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

*1.html*

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="depend/compatibility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="depend/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="depend/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="depend/spin.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="depend/jquery.spin.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="depend/pdf.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="depend/hack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="depend/l10n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="depend/debugger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%"></canvas>
```

*2.js*

```
PDFJS.getDocument("hello.pdf").then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(3).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
        var scale = 1.5;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        page.render({
            canvasContext : context,
            viewport : viewport
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're getting any errors in the console for these browsers, that would be helpful for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

From the `pdf.js` [FAQ](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support)

> IE8 and below are missing too many features to be supported.

You could try [viewer.js](http://viewerjs.org/) but that most likely won't work as I believe it uses `pdf.js`.

Comment: OP said he is using IE9 and IE10, which according to the FAQ have limited support.

Comment: @Jamil yeah,I mean he need try to viewer.js and reading FAQ guide